# How to harmonize ^2 - ^4 - ^3

Tags: chord-progressions, voice-leading, functional-harmony

I have at my disposal I, I6, V and V7 and inversions as well as ii, ii6 and IV to harmonize this melody. I am also allowed to use the cadential 64. I am stuck on the beginning part on how to harmonize ^2 to ^4. I could use the cadential 64 on the first beat of bar 2 but I think that, given the bass notes below, the cadential V is on beat 3 of the second bar. That is why I began bar 2 with I moving to ii6. The reason I am stuck at the beginning is because if the ^4 is part of a V7 then having a subdominant chord for the 1st chord wont work because the 7th wont be prepared. Am I right then in saying that the only option I have then is to harmonize the first 2 chords with V7 chords or inversions? That way the 7th would be transferred from an inner voice in the 1st chord to the soprano in the 2nd chord.
[image]

Comment: I just realized that a very valid option for my needs could be the vii°6 chord... I forgot to add this as my list of available chords but it is indeed available to me and would be a good candidate for the second chord in harmonizing this melody.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your 2–4–3 in the soprano, I would include the next scale-degree 2, as well. This way, a 2–4–3–2 soprano line could be harmonized with voice exchanges in contrary motion in the bass to prolong ii.

The 2–4 in the soprano could be harmonized with 4–2 in the bass, moving from a ii<sup>6</sup> to a ii. Then, the 4–3–2 in the soprano could be harmonized with a 2–3–4 in the bass, ending back on your prior ii<sup>6</sup>.

As for the scale-degree 3, remember that inversions of tonic can prolong predominant chords. Thus, in your progression from ii to ii<sup>6</sup>, you can insert a I<sup>6</sup> that functions as a passing chord to prolong predominant.

All of this, of course, will smoothly move to the cadential six-four on beat 3 of the second measure.

Comment: Ok so the chords in order would be ii6 ii I6 ii6 with the I6 functioning as an expansion of supertonic harmony? And this works even though the I6 chord occurs on the accented beat in the bar?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.   If it breaks any rules, I don't think they're ones that matter!

[image]

Comment: I am have not yet seen chords like the ones on beat 3 in bar 2 yet so unfortunately cant use them. Is that a sus 4 chord?

Comment: Yes.  You've seen one now, and you even knew what to call it.  Amaze your teacher!